# NHibernate schema export issue with Oracle Blob field

Tags: oracle, nhibernate, types, nhibernate-mapping

I'm having an issue creating my Oracle DB with schemaexport function of NHibernate.
For a property defined as byte[], it creates a DB field of type RAW (btw limited to 2000 byte).
This field type is not enough for my needs, and I need NH to create a blob field instead.
How can I achive that?
I tried declaring the field in the mapping file (I use xml mapping, thus hbm files) specifying either type="Binary" and type="BinaryBlob", but none of those seems to have the desired effects: the created field is always a RAW.
Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<property name="prop">
  <column name="blobcolumn" sql-type="BinaryBlob">
</property>
```

Update: maybe this could also do the trick

```
<property name="prop" type="Binary" length="1000000"/>
```

Comment: can you point me where you find the sql-type possible values? And what's the difference with `type="BinaryBlob"`?

Comment: `sql-type` is there to specify database types present in your Database. I don't know if there are predefined values or if it is only sent as string in sqlcreatescript

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and the solution is the length attribute:

```
<property name="Attachment" length="5224880"/>
```

If you specify no length then whatever you write in the type attribute it's going to end as RAW(2000) in oracle because its maximum is 2000 bytes, but if you say I need 5 MB or in bytes its 5224880 bytes  then nhibernate switch's to BLOB automatically because it's bigger then 2000 bytes

so given the dot net property

```
 public virtual byte[] Attachment { get; set; }
```

the proper mapping would be

```
<property name="Attachment" length="5224880"/>
```

Or you can explore the OracleLiteDialect.cs in the codebase (source code) of Nhibernate

Answer (score 0):

If someone wants a convention way to do the byte[] type translate into BLOB in database i came up with this:

```
public class ByteArrayToDbBlobConvention : IPropertyConvention, IPropertyConventionAcceptance
{
    public void Accept(IAcceptanceCriteria<IPropertyInspector> criteria)
    {
        criteria.Expect(x => x.Type == typeof(byte[]));            
    }

    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        instance.CustomSqlType("BLOB");
    }
}
```